# Unexpected token: operator (>) when trying to minify the javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to minify my javascript code using an online tool but everytime I try to do that I get this error:

```
// Error : Unexpected token: operator (>)
// Line  : 1
// Col   : 41
```

and this is on line 1:

```
var result = parsedObject.filter( audio => audio.filename === ''+audioFile+'' );
```

Could someone please advice on this issue and how to resolve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: propably your tool doesn't support ES6 syntax

Comment: Maybe it does not support ES6

Comment: Which tool are you using?

Comment: @BilltheLizard, the top two tools that i found on Google search..

Comment: add compiler ´Babel´...

Comment: JamesJuanjie - That doesn't answer @Bill's question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, neither does his question help to answer my question!

Comment: JamesJuanjie - It would, if you bothered to answer it. What possible reason is there **not** to? Don't you want to help people help you? What if @Bill or anyone else coming to the question happens to know that the tool(s) you're trying to use have an option to enable ES2015+ features? Boom! Answer!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, that makes sense.. this is one of the tools: https://cssminifier.com/

Comment: JamesJuanjie - You're not using cssminifier to minify **JavaScript**. You might be using its associated https://javascript-minifier.com/.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, OMG, wrong link. sorry. i meant this one: https://jscompress.com/

Comment: and this one: https://javascript-minifier.com/

Comment: JamesJuanjie - And indeed, jscompress.com has an option for it -- I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, your minifier doesn't understand [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), or it needs some option to be set to know you're doing ES2015+ ("ES6+") stuff. Your options are:

1. If it has an option, turn the option on; or

   *(you've now told us that you tried both https://jscompress.com/ and https://javascript-minifier.com/. jscompress.com has an "ECMAScript 2018 (via Babili)" tickbox in the upper right-hand corner that, when ticked, minifies your example code. I didn't find an option on javascript-minifier.com.)*
2. If it doesn't, switch to a mninifier that does understand them; or
3. Don't use arrow functions. In this particular case that would look like:

   ```
   var result = parsedObject.filter(function(audio) {
       return audio.filename === ''+audioFile+'';
   });
   ```
4. Use arrow function, but turn them into non-arrows before minifying by using a transpiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io).

If you need to support any version of IE, you need to not send arrow functions to the browser (by using option 3 or 4 above). If you don't have to support IE, just modern browsers like Edge, Chrome, Firefox, and Safari, sending arrow functions to the browser is just fine.

---

Side note: You don't need those `''` on either side of `audioFile`. If it's already a string, just remove them (`=== audioFile`). If it isn't already a string, just do one or the other, or use `String(audioFile)` to convert it, and do it **once** before the `filter` loop:

```
var audioFileString = String(audioFile); // or `'' + audioFile` or `audioFile + ''`
var result = parsedObject.filter(function(audio) {
    return audio.filename === audioFileString;
});
```

Comment: also, https://github.com/JeffreyWay/laravel-mix/issues/790#issuecomment-365756483 might help

Comment: I tried to turn on option that enable use of lambda operator in minified file but not able to turn on, then i tried for 3rd option mentioned and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The tool you are using does not support arrow functions (which are a *relatively* new feature).

You can:

- Find a minifying tool which supports modern JS
- Not use arrow functions in the first place
- Use a tool to transform your JS to ES5 before minifying it